# Resizing an element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this terminal but I can't seem to resize it (it's always the width of the page) and I can't write anything.

What's the problem here?

```css
#terminal2 {
  width: 50px;;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/2.9.2/xterm.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/2.9.2/xterm.js"></script>

<div id="terminal2"></div>
<script>
  var term = new Terminal();
  term.open(document.getElementById('#terminal2'));
  term.write('Hello from \033[1;3;31mxterm.js\033[0m $ ')
</script>
```

Comment: term.open(document.getElementById('#terminal2')); is wrong, should be term.open(document.getElementById('terminal2'));

Comment: you are right lol :D

Comment: do you know how I can write here?

Comment: where do you want to write ? im confused

Comment: in the console.

Comment: term.write('Write something to terminal...')

Comment: @Dirk but I can't actually type on the terminal

Comment: i have no idea, never used this terminal, i suggest you read the documentation on how to use it

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/2.9.2/xterm.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/2.9.2/xterm.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #terminal2 {
      width: 500px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
            var term = new Terminal();
            var tt = document.getElementById('terminal2')
            term.open(tt);
            term.write('Hello from \033[1;3;31mxterm.js\033[0m $ ')
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <div id="terminal2"></div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var term = new Terminal();
    var tt = document.getElementById('terminal2');
    term.open(tt);
    term.write('Hello from \033[1;3;31mxterm.js\033[0m $ ')
}
```

```css
#terminal2 {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/2.9.2/xterm.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xterm/2.9.2/xterm.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <div id="terminal2"></div>
<div>
```